# On a von Bahr–Esseen-type inequality for pairwise independent zero-mean random variables

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, inequalities

For $p\in(1,2)$, let $C_p$ be the smallest constant factor $C$ in the von Bahr–Esseen-type inequality
\begin{equation}\label{eq:pair}\tag{1}
    E\Bigl\lvert\sum_{j=1}^n X_j\Bigr\rvert^p\le C\sum_{j=1}^n E\lvert X_j\rvert^p  
\end{equation}
for all natural $n$ and all **pairwise** independent zero-mean real-valued random variables $X_1,\dotsc,X_n$.

According to [Theorem 4.4](https://arxiv.org/abs/2210.04391),
\begin{equation}\label{eq:C<}
    C_p\le\frac4{2-p}.   
\end{equation}

---

Questions:

> **Q1:** Is it true that $\sup_{p\in(1,2)}C_p<\infty$?

> **Q2:** Is it true that $\inf_{p\in(1,2)}\big((2-p)C_p\big)>0$?

> **Q3:** Is there a simply described asymptotic behavior of $C_p$ as $p\uparrow2$?

> **Q3a:** Is there a simply described asymptotic behavior of the smallest constant factor $C$ in \eqref{eq:pair} as $p\uparrow2$ assuming also that each $X_j$ is symmetrically distributed?

> Any correct and complete answer to any one of these four questions will be considered a correct and complete answer to this entire post.

Of course, an answer to Q3 or Q3a will also be an answer to Q1 and Q2. Also, a positive answer to Q1 would imply a negative answer to Q2, and a positive answer to Q2 would imply a negative answer to Q1.

By [Proposition 1.8 (iii)](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-functional-analysis/volume-6/issue-4/Best-possible-bounds-of-the-von-Bahr--Esseen-type/10.15352/afa/06-4-1.full), letting $D_p$ denote the smallest constant factor $C$ in \eqref{eq:pair}
for all natural $n$ and all **completely** independent zero-mean real-valued random variables $X_1,\dotsc,X_n$, we have $D_p\to1$ as $p\uparrow2$. More generally, here we may assume that the $X_j$'s are martingale-differences (or, even, satisfy another, slightly more general condition).

Comment: Titles of the papers: Theorem 4.4 is from your [Multidimensional probability inequalities via spherical symmetry](https://arxiv.org/abs/2210.04391); Proposition 1.8(iii) is from your [Best possible bounds of the von Bahr–Esseen type](https://doi.org/10.15352/afa/06-4-1).

Comment: @LSpice : When a link is available, I almost never reproduce the titles of any papers in my MO posts, and in most cases I also omit the authors' names. This should correspond to referencing, in a publication, a paper as (say) just "[13]", rather than "Smith [13]".

Comment: Thanks for [explaining](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1112730)!  Unfortunately, while the bibliography for a paper is almost always available in the same place as the paper is, links can rot, so that untitled links leave people looking for Theorem 4.4 in an unknown paper.  I tend to like inline descriptions of the work being referenced, but that's just personal preference; some people put the bibliographies for their MO questions or answers at the end, which also works.  Or, of course, it can be omitted entirely, and I can leave a comment. 

Comment: @LSpice : I too can now see you point -- thank you for the explanation. I hope the links to the papers will last at least as long, though, as any interest to my MO posts. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a positive answer to Q1.

Step 1: Without loss of generality, each $X_i$ is symmetrically distributed. Indeed, consider an independent copy $X_i'$ of the family $X_i$ with the same joint distribution. Then
$$
E\left|\sum_i X_i\right|^p\le E\left|\sum_i (X_i-X_i')\right|^p
$$
(only the mean $0$ property and the convexity of $x\mapsto |x|^p$ are used here) while
$$
E|X_i-X_i'|^p\le 2^p E|X_i|^p
$$
and $X_i-X_i'$ are still pairwise independent.

Now choose $Q>0$ so that $Q^{2-p}=2$. Clearly, $Q\ge 2$. Define $X_{i,k}=X_i$ if $Q^k\le|X_i|< Q^{k+1}$ and $0$ otherwise ($k\in\mathbb Z$). Also denote by $Y_{\ell,k}$ the characteristic function of the event $Q^{\ell+k}\le\left|\sum_i X_{i,k}\right|<Q^{\ell+k+1}$ ($\ell\in\mathbb Z$).

Step 2: The key estimates:
When $\ell\ge 0$, we have
$$
E\left[Y_{\ell,k}\left|\sum_i X_{i,k}\right|^p\right]\le Q^{(p-2)(\ell+k)}E\left|\sum_i X_{i,k}\right|^2
\\
=Q^{(p-2)(\ell+k)}\sum_i E\left|X_{i,k}\right|^2\le 2Q^{(p-2)\ell}\sum_i E|X_{i,k}|^p=2^{1-\ell}\sum_i E|X_{i,k}|^p
$$
because $Q^{(p-2)k}|x|^2\le 2|x|^p$ when $x=0$ or $Q^k\le|x|<Q^{k+1}$.

If $\ell<0$, then
$$
E\left[Y_{\ell,k}\left|\sum_i X_{i,k}\right|^p\right]\le Q^{p(\ell+1)}\sum_i E|X_{i,k}|^p\le 2^{1+\ell}\sum_i E|X_{i,k}|^p
$$
merely because the absolute value of the sum (if not zero) is less than $Q^{\ell+1}$ times the absolute value of any non-zero term in it.

Step 3: Summing over k with fixed $\ell$. The crucial point here is that if we have any sequence of random variables $F_k$ such that the absolute value of $F_k$ is either $0$ or between $Q^{\ell+k}$ and $Q^{\ell+k+1}$, then
$$
\left|\sum_k F_k\right|^p\le 4^p\max_k|F_k|^p\le 4^p\sum_k|F_k|^p\,.
$$
It follows that
$$
E\left|\sum_k \left[Y_{\ell,k}\sum_i X_{i,k}\right]\right|^p\le 4^p\cdot 2^{1-|\ell|}\sum_k \sum_i E|X_{i,k}|^p= 4^p\cdot 2^{1-|\ell|}\sum_i E|X_{i}|^p\,,
$$
i.e.,
$$
\left\|\sum_k \left[Y_{\ell,k}\sum_i X_{i,k}\right]\right\|_{L^p}\le 4\cdot 2^{(1-|\ell|)/p}\left[\sum_i E|X_{i}|^p\right]^{1/p}\,.
$$

Step 4: Use Minkowski's inequality when summing over $\ell$ now and observe that
$$
\sum_\ell\sum_k \left[Y_{\ell,k}\sum_i X_{i,k}\right]=\sum_i X_i\,.
$$

*Edit:* Chasing the constant.

The technique outlined above is often useful as a replacement of interpolation when the latter fails to work directly for some reason. However, in this case we can utilize the complex interpolation tool in its original form for *symmetric* random variables. Here is how it can be done (I'll even assume that $X_i$ are complex, though it does not matter):

Normalize the variables so that $\sum_i E|X_i|^p=1$. Write each $X_i$ as $e^{\frac 1pG_i}u_i$ with real $G_i$ and $|u_i|=1$ so $\sum_i Ee^{G_i}=1$. Also choose $Y=e^{\frac 1qH}v$ so that $E|Y|^q=Ee^{H}=1$ and
$$
E(Y\sum_i X_i)=\left\|\sum_i X_i\right\|_{L^p}\,.
$$
Now just consider $X_{i,z}=e^{zG_i}u_i$ and $Y_z=e^{(1-z)H}v$ as in the classical proof of the Riesz-Thorin interpolation theorem. The trick is that this modification of $X_i$ does not preserve the mean $0$ property in general but *does* preserve symmetry (which informally merely means that for every given value of $G_i$ we have every value of $u_i$ together with its opposite). Also, since $X_{i,z}$ is constructed based on the values of $X_i$ alone, the pairwise independence is also preserved.

Now we can consider $F(z)=E(Y_z\sum_i X_{i,z})$ as an analytic in the strip $\frac 12\le\Re z\le 1$ function, as usual, and use the trivial endpoint estimates ($p=1$ and $p=2$) to get the whole range with constant $1$ for the *symmetric* case.

The crude reduction to the symmetric case yields then the extra factor $2^p$, but it one thinks for just a moment, one realizes that this constant is actually improving, not deteriorating, as we move from $1$ to $2$. So the question becomes the following:

Let $a_p$ and $A_p$ be the best constants in the inequality
$$
a_pE|Z|^p \le E|Z-Z'|^p\le A_pE|Z|^p
$$
where $Z$ is a mean $0$ random variable (real, complex, or Hilbert-space valued: it should, probably, be irrelevant though the original question was about the real case). What is the ratio $A_p/a_p$? It is easy to see that $a_1=1$ while $A_1=2$ explaining the jump discontinuity at $1+$, but it is also easy to see that $a_p,A_p\to 2$ as $p\to 2$, so there is no discontinuity there. I suspect that those values are just known, so I'll wait a bit before thinking of what I can prove myself here.

*Edit 2*. Two more remarks.

1. One can also prove by complex interpolation a slightly more general inequality
   $$
   E\left|\sum_i(X_i-EX_i)\right|\le 2^{2-p}\sum_iE|X_i|^p
   $$
   for arbitrary $X_i$ (not necessarily mean $0$). All it takes is to notice that $X_{i,z}-EX_{i,z}$ depends on $z$ analytically as well. This circumvents the reduction to the symmetric case though the symmetric case with sharp constant $1$ may be of interest by itself.

*Edit: Adding some details by Iosif's request:*

For a random variable $X$, define $X_{i,z}=X^{[pz]}-EX^{[pz]}$ (with $X^{[pz]}$ defined as in Iosif's post). Put $S_z=\sum_i X_{i,z}=\sum_i(X_i^{[pz]}-EX_i^{[pz]})$. Then $X_{i,1/p}=X_i-EX_i$ and $S_{1/p}=S=\sum_i(X_i-EX_i)$. Put $Y_z$ to be exactly the same as in Iosif's post and define
$$
F(z)=E \bar Y^{[q(1-z)]}S_z
$$
Then $F(1/p)=\|S\|_p$ while for $\Re z=1$, we have $|F(z)|\le 2$ ($\|Y_z\|_\infty\le 1$ and $\|\sum_i X_{i,z}\|_1\le 2$), while for $\Re z=1/2$, we have $\|Y_z\|_2\le 1$ and $\|S_z\|_2^2=\sum_i\|X_{i,z}\|^2\le\sum_i\|X_i^{[pz]}\|_2^2=1$, so $|F(z)|\le 1$ ($X_{i,z}$ are independent mean zero, hence orthogonal, and subtracting the mean can only reduce the $L^2$-norm (but can raise the $L^1$-norm twice)).

Now consider $F(z)2^{1-2z}$ ($z-1$ in the comment was a typo). This function is bounded by $1$ on both lines, so everywhere. For $z=1/p$, this gives
$$
\|S\|_p=F(1/p)=2^{\frac 2p-1}(F(1/p)2^{1-\frac 2p})\le 2^{\frac 2p-1}
$$
and, raising both sides to the $p$-th power, we get
$$
E|S|^p\le 2^{2-p}\,.,
$$

2. Let $\varepsilon>0$. Consider $m$ sets $F_i$ of measure $\epsilon$ with pairvise intersections of measure $\varepsilon^2$ but no triple intersections (they are easy to construct by induction when $m\varepsilon<1$). Then $X_i=\chi_{F_i}-\varepsilon$ are pairwise independent with mean $0$ and $E|X_i|^p=\varepsilon(1-\varepsilon)^p+(1-\varepsilon)\varepsilon^p$. On the other hand,
   $$
   E\left|\sum_i X_i\right|^p=
   \\
   m(\varepsilon-(m-1)\varepsilon^2)(1-m\varepsilon)^p+\frac{m(m-1)}2\varepsilon^2(2-m\varepsilon)^p
   \\
   +\left(1-m\varepsilon+\frac{m(m-1)}2\varepsilon^2\right)(m\varepsilon)^p\,.
   $$
   Considering the regime $\varepsilon\to 0$, $m\varepsilon\to x\in(0,1)$, we get
   $$
   (x-x^2)(1-x)^p+\tfrac{x^2}2(2-x)^p+(1-x+\tfrac{x^2}2)x^p\le C_p x\,.
   $$
   Thus,
   $$
   C_p\ge (1-x)^{p+1}+\tfrac x2(2-x)^p+(1-x+\tfrac{x^2}2)x^{p-1}
   $$
   for every $x\in(0,1)$.

The graph of the maximum of the RHS over $x\in(0,1)$ is below (in red) compared to $2^{2-p}$ (in green) but it is clear that for $x$ close to $0$ the RHS tends to a number close to $2$ when $p\to 1$ (the first and the third term will be about $1$ each), so $C_{1+}=2$.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Very clever, as usual. I did think about exponential partitioning, but was far from your technique. When asking this question, I thought you would be the one who could answer it, which now has happened. :-) Just some minor remarks: (i) What you did in Step 2 for $\ell\ge0$ seems to work for all $\ell$ (even though you need a better bound for $\ell<0$). (ii) In the first display in Step 3, it seems possible to replace $4^p$ by $3^p$. (iii) Even then, the constant factor for $p=2$ is $>600$, by my calculations. Certainly $<\infty$, but still rather large.

Comment: May I include your proof (perhaps slightly modified) into the linked paper, at https://arxiv.org/abs/2210.04391? Of course, in any case, I would refer to your answer.

Comment: @IosifPinelis You are most cordially welcome! (i) Of course, but it doesn't give anything useful for $\ell<0$ (ii) That particular factor can even be replaced by $1+o(1)$ as $p\to 2$ with some more accurate considerations but I didn't try to chase the constants since I wasn't getting $1$ anyway (iii) With that modification, one can get $C_p\le 16+o(1)$ as $p\to 2$ but I don't see much difference between $16$ and $600$ when the suspected answer is just $1$. (iv) Everything that I communicate publicly can be used in any way by anybody with or without reference.

Comment: Thank you for your usual generosity. Of course, I will make a proper reference to your work if I get a chance to use it (the paper is now under review). I will try to get $16+o(1)$ or, perhaps, you can share that with me. I am not sure that $1$ is the right answer. Even when the $X_i$'s are completely independent, the best constant factor $C(p)$ is discontinuous (in that case, at $p=1$, with $C(1+)=2$; Proposition 1.8 (iii) in https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-functional-analysis/volume-6/issue-4/Best-possible-bounds-of-the-von-Bahr--Esseen-type/10.15352/afa/06-4-1.full ).

Comment: Previous comment continued: When the $X_i$'s are only pairwise independent, it seems that we only can use the additivity of the 2nd (possibly truncated) moments, which appears to create a (near-)singularity when $p$ is close to $2$.

Comment: @IosifPinelis I'm also not sure that $1$ is the correct answer but so far all my attempts to construct a counterexample failed. Perhaps I just don't know many examples of pairwise independent random variables :-). I guess I'll spend a few more days thinking of it and will update you if I find anything interesting.

Comment: @IosifPinelis OK, I found something interesting that you may like. See the edit :-)

Comment: @IosifPinelis $A_p=2$ for all $p\in[1,2]$ (the same complex interpolation though it might be an overkill). I'm still not sure about $a_p$. My suspicion is that it is $2^{p-1}$, i.e., Rademacher is the worst case but the proof still escapes me. But even the trivial estimate $a_p\ge 1$ gives $C_p\le 2$ for all $p\in[1,2]$ :-).

Comment: @fedja Yes, the value $a_{p}=2^{p-1}$ is known. See theorem 1.2 here https://arxiv.org/pdf/1905.01274.pdf

Comment: @PaataIvanishvili Indeed. The same complex interpolation but a cute trick of reducing the lower bound to the upper bound for some linear operator applied to a function of two variables. That was new to me. Thanks! Thus $C_p\le 2^{2-p}$. I wonder whether that is sharp now.

Comment: $2^{2-p}$ sounds great. Can you detail "Now we can consider $F(z)=E(Y_z\sum_i X_{i,z})$ as an analytic in the strip $\frac 12\le\Re z\le 1$ function, as usual, and use the trivial endpoint estimates ($p=1$ and $p=2$) to get the whole range with constant $1$ for the *symmetric* case."? In particular, I am not sure what relation, if any, you mean here between $F(z)$ and $\|\sum_i X_i\|_p$. Also, you meant $H$ to be real and $|v|=1$, and $q$ dual to $p$, right?

Comment: @IosifPinelis $F(1/p)=\|\sum_i X_i\|_p$ by the construction. The function $F(z)$ is bounded by $1$ on the boundary of the strip and is continuous up to the boundary and bounded by something large but fixed a priori, so the maximum principle applies and we get $|F(1/p)|\le 1$, which is exactly what we want. Yes to the rest.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Feel free to ask more questions any time if anything remains unclear :-)

Comment: @IosifPinelis I tried to read your example of $C_{1+}=2$ and noticed that in the paper you referenced the meaning of $C_p$ is different: the inequality there is $E|\sum_i X_i|^p\le E|X_1|^p+C_p\sum_{i\ge 2}E|X_i|^p$ and the example gives the sharp value only for that inequality and (unless I misunderstand what is written) only for $n=2$. This doesn't seem to imply that our $C_{1+}$ (which is a factor at *all* $E|X_i|^p$, including $i=1$) is still $2$. Probably I'm just missing something simple, but it was a long day, so can you clarify what you meant and what example you had in mind here?

Comment: Right, I forgot what $C_p$ actually was there. Concerning your answer, I still don't see how you get $|F(z)|\le1$ for $\Re z=1/2$. Apparently, it is here that you use the pairwise independence -- but I don't see how. Could you please explain this?

Comment: @IosifPinelis When $\Re z=1/2$, the r.v. $X_{i,z}$ satisfy $\sum_i E|X_{i,z}|^2=1$ and they are symmetric and pairwise independent, hence orthogonal, so $\|\sum_i X_{i,z}\|_2=1$ while $\|Y_z\|_2=1$ as well and Cauchy-Schwarz finishes the story.

Comment: I see, thank you -- just Cauchy--Schwarz. This is great!

Comment: @IosifPinelis Let's try to find some decent lower bound for $C_p$ now :-)

Comment: @fedja : I have written a presentation (https://mathoverflow.net/a/438604/36721) of the second part of your answer, in a way that would be more accessible to me. I hope you don't mind -- please let me know otherwise.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Why should I mind? If someone's mother tongue is English and I send him a note in Russian, it is only natural that he would translate it before storing it :lol: But once you bumped it to the front page anyway, I'll try to edit my post once again today, adding two more remarks (in particular, showing that $C_{1+}=2$, indeed, as you said)

Comment: @IosifPinelis Done. I don't know if the lower bound is actually the truth in the mean zero version, but if it is, the proof will require a completely different technique, so it will take some time to figure it out anyway...

Comment: Thank you for Edit 2. Concerning its part 2, I think there should be $1-m\varepsilon-\frac{m(m-1)}2\varepsilon^2$ instead of $1-m\varepsilon+\frac{m(m-1)}2\varepsilon^2$, and then $1-x-\frac{x^2}2$ instead of $1-x+\frac{x^2}2$. Then, to get $C_{1+}=2$, you can let $x=p-1\downarrow0$.

Comment: Previous comment continued: Instead of the induction on $m$, you can use the construction on p. 4 of Ref. [9] in the paper linked in my question on this MO page, with $n=m$, $x_2=\varepsilon^2$, $x_1=\varepsilon-(n-1)\varepsilon^2$, and $x_0:=1-nx_1-\frac{n(n-1)}2\,x_2$. I had tried to use that to show that $C_{2-}=\infty$ -- of course, in vain.

Comment: Concerning part 1 of Edit 2, I am not sure what modifications to make (say in my presentation of your proof) to get $2^{2-p}$, even though the analyticity is clear.

Comment: @IosifPinelis 1) Nope, it is correct: we are looking there at the part covered by no $E_j$, so $1$ minus the sum of measures ($m\varepsilon$) *plus* the overlap. 2) Almost none. Just multiply by $2^{z-1}$ before applying the maximum principle.

Comment: @fedja : 1) Of course, you are right. I don't know how I got the $+$ in the expression for $x_0$. 2) I still don't see how to modify the proof for zero-mean $X_i$'s. In particular, I don't know what you want to multiply by $2^{z-1}$. Could you just describe the needed modifications of $Y_z$, $S_z$, and $F(z)$, preferably in the explicit style they are described in my answer?

Comment: @IosifPinelis OK, but a few hours later :-)

Comment: @fedja : Thank you.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Done. I tried to follow your notation but might be a bit clumsy with it, so let me know if something I wrote does not make sense.

Comment: Thank you again. I have just fixed some typos.

Comment: @fedja : It seems that the inequality $E\big|\sum_{j=1}^n X_j\big|^p\le E|X_1|^p+\tilde C_p\sum_{j=2}^n E|X_j|^p$ with $\tilde C_p$ as in Proposition 1.8 in https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-functional-analysis/volume-6/issue-4/Best-possible-bounds-of-the-von-Bahr--Esseen-type/10.15352/afa/06-4-1.full could be proved by your interpolation method for zero-mean pairwise independent $X_j$'s.

Comment: The key step here seems to extend $\tilde C_p$ analytically to all complex $p$ with $\Re\frac1p\in(\frac12,1)$ and then continuously to $p$ with $\Re\frac1p\in[\frac12,1]$ so that the extension be $\le1$ in modulus for $\Re\frac1p\in\{\frac12,1\}$. The analyticity could be attained by taking the rather straightforward analytic extensions of the approximations by the Newton or secant method of the root $x_p\in((p-1)/5,(p-1)/2)$ of equation (1.14) in that paper. What do you think?

Comment: @IosifPinelis Hmmm. I'm not sure what you mean by an "analytic extension" of a constant in an inequality but I'll take a look later.

Comment: @fedja : In your latter argument, the "constant" $c(p):=2^{2-p}$ is a function of $p$, and your factor $g(z):=2^{1-2z}$ is an analytic extension of $g(t)=2^{1-2t}=c(1/t)^{-t}$ for $t\in(1/2,1)$, if I am not mistaken. So, one may say your argument is based, in part, on the analytic extension $c(z):=2^{2-z}=g(1/z)^{-z}$ of the "constant" $c(p):=2^{2-p}$. I was wondering if one can similarly extend $\tilde C_p$ to some appropriate $\tilde C_z$, using (say) approximations by the Newton or secant method. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb C}\newcommand{\p}[2]{#1^{[#2]}}\newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}$This is to provide another presentation of the second part of fedja's very ingenious [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/438251/36721).

The main differences are the following: (i) this presentation is more detailed and (ii) notation is simplified -- everything is expressed explicitly in terms of $p$, the $X_i$'s, and $z\in\C$, without using the symbols $G_i,u_i,H,v$.

> **Theorem:** Suppose that $p\in[1,2]$, $S:=\sum_i X_i$, $\sum_i:=\sum_{i=1}^n$, and $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are independent symmetric random variables (r.v.'s) with values in $\C$ (so that $-X_i$ has the same distribution as $X_i$, for each $i$). Then
> \begin{equation*}
>     E|S|^p\le\sum_i E|X_i|^p. \tag{10}\label{10}
> \end{equation*}

*Proof:* Inequality \eqref{10} is obvious when $p=1$ or $p=2$. So, it makes sense to try to interpolate between these two cases for $p$.

First, some **preliminaries**. Without loss of generality (wlog) $p\in(1,2]$, so that one can define $q:=\frac p{p-1}$, and then $\frac1p+\frac1q=1$.
If $E|S|^p=0$ or $E|X_i|^p=\infty$ for some $i$, then \eqref{10} is trivial. So, wlog  $\|S\|_p:=(E|S|^p)^{1/p}>0$ and $E|X_i|^p<\infty$ for all $i$. By the power-means inequality, $|S|^p\le n^{p-1}\sum_i|X_i|^p$. So, by (symmetric) truncation of the $X_i$'s and dominated convergence, wlog the $X_i$'s are bounded. Also, wlog
\begin{equation*}
    \sum_i E|X_i|^p=1. \tag{20}\label{20}
\end{equation*}

For complex $x$ and $z$, let
\begin{equation*}
    \p xz:=|x|^{z-1}x
\end{equation*}
if $x\ne0$, with $\p0z:=0$. For such $x$ and $z$,

- $\p xz$ is holomorphic in $z$;
- $|\p xz|=|x|^{\Re z}$;
- $\p xz$ is odd in $x$, that is, $\p{(-x)}z=-\p xz$;
- so, if $X$ is a symmetric $\C$-valued r.v., then the r.v. $\p Xz$ is symmetric as well.

Now, the **construction**: For $z\in\C$, let
\begin{equation*}
    F(z):=E Y_z S_z,
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    Y_z:=\p{\bar Y}{(1-z)q},\quad Y:=\frac{\p S{p-1}}{\|S\|_p^{p-1}},\quad S_z:=\sum_i\p{X_i}{pz},
\end{equation*}
and $\;\bar{}\ $ denotes the complex conjugation. Then

- $F\colon\C\to\C$ is an entire function;
- If $z=\frac1p$, then $Y_z=\bar Y=\dfrac{\p{\bar S}{p-1}}{\|S\|_p^{p-1}}$ and $S_z=S$, so that
  \begin{equation*}
      F(\tfrac1p)=\|S\|_p. \tag{30}\label{30}
  \end{equation*}
- If $\Re z=1$, then $|Y_z|\in\{0,1\}$ and $|\p{X_i}{pz}|=|X_i|^p$, so that $|F(z)|\le E|S_z|\le\sum_i E|X_i|^p=1$ by \eqref{20}.
- If $\Re z=\frac12$, then $|Y_z|^2=|Y|^q=\Big(\dfrac{|S|^{p-1}}{\|S\|_p^{p-1}}\Big)^q=\dfrac{|S|^p}{\|S\|_p^p}$, $E|Y_z|^2=1$, and
  $E|S_z|^2=\sum_i E|\p{X_i}{pz}|^2=\sum_i E|X_i|^p=1$, since the $\p{X_i}{pz}$'s are pairwise independent symmetric r.v.'s and in view of \eqref{20}. So, by the Cauchy--Schwarz inequality, $|F(z)|\le1$ if $\Re z=\frac12$.

So, $|F|\le1$ on the boundary of the strip $T:=\{z\in\C\colon\Re z\in[\frac12,1]\}$. Also, the entire function $F$ is bounded on $T$, since the $X_i$'s are bounded.

So, by the [Phragmén–Lindelöf principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phragm%C3%A9n%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_principle#Example_of_application), $|F|\le1$ on the entire strip $T$. Since $\frac1p\in T$, and in view of \eqref{30}, we conclude that $\|S\|_p\le1$, which is equivalent to \eqref{10}, in view of \eqref{20}. $\quad\Box$